# Turn off location services automatically, when app is no longer in foreground

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, geolocation, multitasking

I want location services to only be on when certain apps like maps are being *used*. I understand that maps stays in the background now since ios 8, and thus location services will stay on. Is there a workaround for this? For example disabling background services for certain apps

Comment: not sure in iOS 8, you can in iOS 9. Settings > Privacy > Location Services. Some apps can be told 'only while using' but some only have on/off

Comment: @Tetsujin but if I exit the app, would location services still be on? It's still running in the background right?

Comment: If it's in the background, you're not using it are you?